# Count Views Per User?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Just want to know how can we get total number of hits per page for per user through apex class.
My apex code is as below:

```
public class EditCustomerData
{
    integer count=0;
    public void trackVisits()
    {
        count=count+1;
        Tracking_1__c track=new Tracking_1__c(
        Users__c=UserInfo.getUserId(),
      VF_Page_Visited__c='https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/apex/EditCustomerData',
        Datetime_Visited__c=datetime.now(),
        Counter__c=count
        );
        insert track;
    }
}
```

My visual force code is as below:

```
<apex:page controller="EditCustomerData" showHeader="true" action="{!trackVisits}">

</apex:page>
```

But every time count values is 1. Is there any other way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: If you can wait for the Summer '17 release, you'll be able to use Visualforce Metrics. See this article by Bob Buzzard: http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2017/06/visualforce-page-metrics-in-summer-17.html

Comment: Let's say two users access the same page, then what is your expectation. should there be 2 records in Tracking_1__c object or there should be one record but count should be 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count` will always be 1 because when the class is called, you're declaring a new Integer as 0, adding 1 and creating a new record with the value 1.

From what I can see, there's one of two scenarios you want:

1. Create a new record when a visit is recorded
2. Get a User's Tracking_1__c record for a particular page and increment their count.

### First Scenario

In the first instance, you could literally, each time a User visits a page, create a record:

```
public class EditCustomerData {
  public void trackVisits() {
    Tracking_1__c track = new Tracking_1__c(
      Users__c = UserInfo.getUserId(),
      Datetime_Visited__c = datetime.now(),
      VF_Page_Visited__c = 'apex/EditCustomerData',
    );

    INSERT track;
  }
}
```

Then you can write a simply query to see how often a page is visited:

```
Integer count = [SELECT Count() FROM Tracking_1__c WHERE User = :myUser AND VF_Page_Visited__c = '/apex/EditCustomerData'];
```

There's an argument to say you don't need the `Datetime_Visited__c` because the CreatedDate would be just that.

### Second Scenario

You would need to do a few things:

1. Check if a User has a record for a page
2. If they don't, create it, otherwise get it
3. Get the `Count__c` value
4. Add 1
5. Update it

It might look like below:

```
public class EditCustomerData {
  public void trackVisits() {
    // Get a list of tracking records
    Tracking_1__c[] trackingRecord = [SELECT Counter__c FROM Tracking_1__c WHERE Users__c = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND VF_Page_Visited__c = '/apex/EditCustomerData' LIMIT 1];

    if (trackingRecord.size() > 0) { // Did the query return a record?
      Integer counter = trackingRecord[0].Counter__c; // Assign counter to an Integer
      counter = counter + 1; // Add 1
      trackingRecord[0].Counter__c = counter; // Set counter to the new count
    }
    else { // If there's no record...
      trackingRecord.add(new Tracking_1__c( // ... Create a new one
        Users__c = UserInfo.getUserId(),
        Datetime_Visited__c = datetime.now(),
        VF_Page_Visited__c = '/apex/EditCustomerData',
        Counter__c = 1;
      ));
    }

    UPSERT trackingRecord; // UPSERT (Update or Insert a record)
  }
}
```

The only problem I could see here is that Datetime_Visited__c becomes redundant. It will just show the last time a User visited the page.

As I mentioned in the comments, you might be better waiting for [Summer '17](http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2017/06/visualforce-page-metrics-in-summer-17.html) as they're doing something that will track views to a Page. Although, from what I've experimented with doesn't show it by User, only the total.

Comment: Thanks Dan for your response. You solved my query. Just want to know if we call any method on Page Action, will it impact on any performance issue ?

Comment: One more thing Dan, in 2nd scenario, first time when we call  trackVisits method, there will be no records in Tracking_1__c  table so it will throw error : List has no rows for assignment to SObject.

Comment: On your second comment, you're right it would. I've updated the answer that should handle that. On your first point, it will affect performance because you are making a callout to the server each time the page is loaded. However, I wouldn't expect something this simple to have much of an impact. Mark this as the answer if it's helped enough! :)